# Error in pandas: "Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)"

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen several posts with the same error, but I'm sorry, I still can't properly solve my issue.

Here is my code from a .py file:

```
def get_sum(self, data, list_of_items):
    # I coded this return line, which worked according to one of the cells of the .ipynb file
    # Returns an integer summing up all of the 1s in a given column (or set of columns)
    return data.iloc[:, list_of_items].all(axis = 'columns').sum()


def get_list(self, data):
    
    basket = [[i] for i in data.columns]
    product_list = []

    for item in basket:
        # I coded these two lines, which I am unable to test due to the error
        if self.get_sum(data, [item]) >= 5:
            product_list.append(item)
    
    return product_list
```

Which will be accessed by this cell in an .ipynb:

```
basket_list = groceries.get_list(df)
print(basket_list)
# expected to be something like [0, 2]. In the case of the given sample, [1]
```

The error shows up in the first line of the .ipynb cell, but that cannot be as I only changed the .py file (both files were supplied). That being said, I don't know where the error really is because it doesn't point towards anything I've written. If someone could at least drop a hint to what I did wrong, that would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Here is a sample of the data:

```
  0 1 2
0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 0
3 0 1 0
4 1 1 1
5 1 1 0
```

And here is the full error traceback,

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-142-6c2c13d12cb0> in <module>()
----> 1 frequent_itemsets = rule_miner.get_frequent_itemsets(syn_df)
      2 print(frequent_itemsets)

/content/rule_miner.py in get_frequent_itemsets(self, data)
    121                 # this class.
    122 
--> 123                 if self.get_support(data, [itemset]) >= self.support_t:
    124                     new_itemsets.append(itemset)
    125 

/content/rule_miner.py in get_support(self, data, itemset)
     28         # function.
     29 
---> 30         return data.iloc[:, itemset].all(axis = 'columns').sum()
     31 
     32     def merge_itemsets(self, itemsets):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    871                     # AttributeError for IntervalTree get_value
    872                     pass
--> 873             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
    874         else:
    875             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1447             pass
   1448 
-> 1449         return self._getitem_tuple_same_dim(tup)
   1450 
   1451     def _get_list_axis(self, key, axis: int):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_tuple_same_dim(self, tup)
    748                 continue
    749 
--> 750             retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
    751             # We should never have retval.ndim < self.ndim, as that should
    752             #  be handled by the _getitem_lowerdim call above.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1485         # a list of integers
   1486         elif is_list_like_indexer(key):
-> 1487             return self._get_list_axis(key, axis=axis)
   1488 
   1489         # a single integer

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_list_axis(self, key, axis)
   1467         """
   1468         try:
-> 1469             return self.obj._take_with_is_copy(key, axis=axis)
   1470         except IndexError as err:
   1471             # re-raise with different error message

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _take_with_is_copy(self, indices, axis)
   3361         See the docstring of `take` for full explanation of the parameters.
   3362         """
-> 3363         result = self.take(indices=indices, axis=axis)
   3364         # Maybe set copy if we didn't actually change the index.
   3365         if not result._get_axis(axis).equals(self._get_axis(axis)):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in take(self, indices, axis, is_copy, **kwargs)
   3349 
   3350         new_data = self._mgr.take(
-> 3351             indices, axis=self._get_block_manager_axis(axis), verify=True
   3352         )
   3353         return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="take")

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in take(self, indexer, axis, verify, convert)
   1455         new_labels = self.axes[axis].take(indexer)
   1456         return self.reindex_indexer(
-> 1457             new_axis=new_labels, indexer=indexer, axis=axis, allow_dups=True
   1458         )
   1459 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in reindex_indexer(self, new_axis, indexer, axis, fill_value, allow_dups, copy, consolidate)
   1289 
   1290         if axis == 0:
-> 1291             new_blocks = self._slice_take_blocks_ax0(indexer, fill_value=fill_value)
   1292         else:
   1293             new_blocks = [

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in _slice_take_blocks_ax0(self, slice_or_indexer, fill_value, only_slice)
   1369         else:
   1370             blknos = algos.take_1d(
-> 1371                 self.blknos, slobj, fill_value=-1, allow_fill=allow_fill
   1372             )
   1373             blklocs = algos.take_1d(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in take_nd(arr, indexer, axis, out, fill_value, allow_fill)
   1735         arr.ndim, arr.dtype, out.dtype, axis=axis, mask_info=mask_info
   1736     )
-> 1737     func(arr, indexer, out, fill_value)
   1738 
   1739     if flip_order:

pandas/_libs/algos_take_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.algos.take_1d_int64_int64()

ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

Comment: please provide the full error traceback, the data as text, the current output, and the expected output

Comment: @mozway the post has been edited. Do let me know if there are other details that you wish to be included.

Comment: It's missing the explanation of what the code is supposed to do and the expected output

Comment: @mozway the expected output is in the second code block. Sorry I wasn't able to point that out better. The expected output pretty much explains what the code is for, but it basically gives the indices of the columns with at least five 1s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a complex custom function, you can use pandas vector functions for that:

get the name of columns with at least five 1:

```
>>> df.columns[df.eq(1).sum().ge(5)]
Index(['1'], dtype='object')
```

filter those columns:

```
df.loc[:, df.eq(1).sum().ge(5)]
```

output:

```
   1
0  0
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  1
5  1
```

How it works:

```
(df.eq(1) # values equal to 1 -> True
   .sum() # count number of True
   .ge(5) # True if sum ≥ 5
)
```

#### fix of OP code:

`loc` used in place of `iloc` and wrong list passed to `get_sum`

```
def get_sum(data, list_of_items):
    # I coded this return line, which worked according to one of the cells of the .ipynb file
    return data.loc[:, list_of_items].all(axis = 'columns').sum()


def get_list(data):
    
    product_list = []

    for item in df.columns:
        # I coded these two lines, which I am unable to test due to the error
        if get_sum(data, [item]) >= 5:
            product_list.append(item)
    
    return product_list
```

Comment: Would it not be possible using `get_sum()`? As much as I'd like to refer to your very clean method, this is kind of a "fill in the blanks" and I need to make use of said function T T

Comment: Well surely, I did append a fix of your code.